# No resource identifier found for attribute while running

Tags: android, ionic2, ionic3

I am getting this error while compiling this on android. 
using: Ionic cordova run android
Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

It is working fine 
using: Ionic lab

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Faran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.10.0
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Faran\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Error

```
D:\2bvision\cardapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:28: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
```

Comment: Anyone have solution for this, I am facing the same issue in  react native. npm run android